# skip the "Unmatched ( in regex; marked by <-- HERE in" error in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have to replace certain String in a file with a new string. I used the following statement.

```
 $tobereplaced="SFK_DFKDG_ASDf(SDGFds gfd"; #example string
 $replace="SFK_DFKDG_ASDf(SDGFds gfd processed"; #example String
 $value =~ s/$tobereplaced/$replace/g;
```

While replacing I got this error
Unmatched ( in regex; marked by <-- HERE in ...

How to avoid this error? Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `\Q` metacharacter to disable the pattern metacharacters in your search string and perform a literal string substitution:

```
$value =~ s/\Q$tobereplaced/$replace/g;
```

More information can be found [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html).